# JIRA : Advanced Search : JQL

Tags: jira, jql

Issue:

Can not view issues that have been marked as 'closed' or 'done' within the last 30 days.

Tried:

```
assignee in (XX, YY) OR assignee in membersOf(AA) AND status in (Closed, Done) AND updatedDate = startOfDay(-30d)
```

Objective:

I need to select issues that are either closed or done be individuals and a group over the last 30 days. Would be so much better if there were a `closedDate` function here.

Comment: What's the result so far? Can you tell us what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Three suggestions which I think may solve your problem:

1. Use parentheses around your assignee condition which uses OR operator to get only issues from assignees "XX", "YY" and members of "AA". Otherwise you would get ALL issues from assignees "XX" and "YY".
2. Try to use `resolutiondate` instead of `updatedDate`, because the last one could have been changed after resolution.
3. Use `>=` instead of `=` to get issues within the last 30 days. Otherwise you would only get issues resolved at this date, if any because of the timepart in this timestamp value.

The final query could look like this:

```
(assignee in (XX, YY) OR assignee in membersOf(AA)) AND status in (Closed, Done) AND resolutiondate >= startOfDay(-30d)
```

Comment: Thanks. 1. I want all of those. 2. Tried that too (before) same result. Tried that argument >=, same result.

Comment: To help you out I need more information. Could you please answer my questions as asked before on your question? What's the result so far? Can you tell us what's wrong with it? What do you expect?

Comment: Check your workflow to see when the resolution date field is set. If it is set when you Close the issue, it will be the thing to use. If it is set when you Resolve an issue (for example) then you might want to look at the JQL "changed to Closed" function at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-CHANGED. More info in the answer at https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/53605/how-to-write-a-jql-to-find-issues-status-changed-on-last-week as well